# Работа с внешними устройствами с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb

Необходимо написать скрипт, управляющий внешним устройством, подключенным через USB. На плате устройства стоит преобразователь USB-UART CH2102. Опыта написания подобных программ нету.

Необходимо работать работать с драйвером устройства(в моем случае cp2102) или же необходимо работать напрямую с USB?

Подскажите пожалуйста как работать с внешними устройствами или где можно об этом прочитать.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Непосредственно библиотека для работы с usb:
[https://pypi.org/project/pywinusb/](https://pypi.org/project/pywinusb/%22https://pypi.org/project/pywinusb/%22) Вот пример использования:
[https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3z346p/reading_a_usb_data_stream_on_windows/](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3z346p/reading_a_usb_data_stream_on_windows/ "https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3z346p/reading_a_usb_data_stream_on_windows/")